# Python: GUI packing widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, pack

This is my program and i packed my widgets so it would be left but somehow when i run it the widgets are not appearing from the left. The person and colour are appearing in the middle but the scary person and creature is appearing on the left. I want person and colour widget to to appear on the left too.

Here is my program

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox 

class StoryMaker:

 def __init__(self):

  # Create the main window.
  self.main_window = Tkinter.Tk()

  #Create nine frames to group widgets.
  self.first_frame = Tkinter.Frame()
  self.second_frame = Tkinter.Frame() 
  self.third_frame = Tkinter.Frame()
  self.fourth_frame = Tkinter.Frame()
  self.fifth_frame = Tkinter.Frame()

  # Create the widgets for the first frame. 
  self.prompt_label = Tkinter.Label(self.first_frame, text='Please enter information for a new story, then click the "Make Story" button.')

  # Create the widgets for the second frame.
  self.person_label = Tkinter.Label(self.second_frame, text='Person: ')
  self.person_entry = Tkinter.Entry(self.second_frame, width= 15)

  # Pack the second frame's widgets.
  self.person_label.pack(side='left')
  self.person_entry.pack(side='left')

  # Create the widgets for the third frame.
  self.colour_label = Tkinter.Label(self.third_frame, text='Colour: ')
  self.colour_entry = Tkinter.Entry(self.third_frame, width= 15)

  # Pack the third frame's widgets.
  self.colour_label.pack(side='left')
  self.colour_entry.pack(side='left')

  # Create the widgets for the fourth frame.
  self.scary_label = Tkinter.Label(self.fourth_frame, text='Scary person or creature: ', justify=LEFT)
  self.scary_entry = Tkinter.Entry(self.fourth_frame, width= 15)

  # Pack the fourth frame's widgets.
  self.scary_label.pack(side='left')
  self.scary_entry.pack(side='left')

  # Pack the frames.
  self.first_frame.pack()
  self.second_frame.pack()
  self.third_frame.pack()
  self.fourth_frame.pack() 
  self.fifth_frame.pack()

  # Enter the Tkinter main loop.
  Tkinter.mainloop()

 my_gui = StoryMaker()
```

Comment: Use a single frame for all widgets & try `grid` instead of `pack`

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I suggest is that you give each of the frames a distinct background color. This is just temporary, so you can see where each frame begins and ends. I think you'll find the results surprising:

```
 self.first_frame = Tkinter.Frame(background="red")
 self.second_frame = Tkinter.Frame(background="pink") 
 self.third_frame = Tkinter.Frame(background="green")
 self.fourth_frame = Tkinter.Frame(background="blue")
 self.fifth_frame = Tkinter.Frame(background="yellow")
```

When you do that you'll quickly see that the problem isn't that the labels are centered, but that the frame they are in is in the center. This is because you packed them with no options, which is the same as saying `...pack(side="top", fill=None, expand=False)`.

If you add `fill="x"`) when packing `first_frame`, `second_frame`, etc, you'll see that your labels and entry widgets are indeed on the left side of their container.

My advice to people who are trying to learn tkinter is to take the "divide and conquer" approach. If you are using intermediate frames to organize your widgets, start by creating *only* those frames. Get the pack or grid options set so that these containing widgets are where you want them, and resize the way you want them to. Only after doing that should you add the interior widgets. That way, at any one time you're only trying to solve the layout problems of one group of widgets at a time.

If you're laying out a form, you might find it easier to use grid rather than pack. Typically in a form all of the labels in a group of labels will be the same size and aligned with each other. That's much easier to do by using grid and placing all of the widgets in a single frame, than it is to use multiple frames.